# angular 5 routing on same component is not working

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to route the same path the second time, but it's not invoking into ngOnInit() to load the new data on the same component.

**app.routing.module.ts:**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: mycomponet}
  {path: 'name', component: nameComponent}
]
@NGModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**app.service.ts**: were my routing logic is placed and I am trying to navigate the `nameComponent` again

```js
let newData = []
nextClick(data) {    
  let condition = true;
  let newData = [];
  if(condition == true) {
    this.router.naviagete(['app-name/name'])
  }
  return this.newData
}
```

**name.component.ts**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.appService.nextClick())
}
```

here my name.component `ngOnInit()` invoking the first time, but when I try to route the same path again it's not invoking. how to navigate the same path with different data (newData)?

Comment: https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2 this post might solve your problem

Comment: navigate is spelled wrongly in nextClick function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are staying on the same path that you are trying to route to , Angular router won't re-initialize the component. It will understand that the requested path is same as the current path. Hence no routing takes place.
You could use an observable in service and pass data to the component if you need to send different data.

Refer this [link](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#Unrelated-Components-Sharing-Data-with-a-Service) for examples

Comment: yes understand, any examples how to pass observable from service to components.. but it’s not invoking oninit itself right? Then where we need to subscribe the Observables?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just reload your component on the same Url, you should use extra options for your RouterModule and use `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'`
https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#onSameUrlNavigation

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for your first answer, it seemed to me that you did not finished your answer for your second case "current component" yet, you might want to finish it to make your answer complete.

Comment: @michael: my components are child components, that is its configured as RouteModule.forChild(routes), in that case these extra option won’t work I Guess?? Any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand I think you are trying to do some logic within your app service and return some data after using that logic back to your component. For the same you need to do the following..

Define newData within your **name.component.ts** and do this:

```
this.appService.nextClick(oldData).subscribe((data) => {
   this.newData = data;
   console.log(this.newData) //to view it in the console if you are trying to do that
},
(error) => {
     //console.error("Error");
});
```

And in app.service just do this:

```
public newData: any[];
nextClick(oldData){ 
    // do something with oldData like oldData = oldData - 1;   
    this.newData = oldData;
    let condition = true;
    if(condition == true){
      return this.newData;
    }
  }
```

Comment: 3Demon: that the nice suggestion, I can use public or Input decorator to store and shred to my child components, but the issue is if I try to navigate the same path again it’s not invoking ngoninit on my name components..

Comment: It is not going to do that unless you use a reload function or something. Like location.reload() to refresh your page. But I would not suggest that because re-routing or reloading the same page is not required here. If you reload it will invoke ngOnInit() again and if you really want to detect changes on the same component you can also use ngOnChanges()